# TCP/IP: connecting immediately after disconnecting

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, connection, disconnect

I’m working on a client and server protocols over TCP/IP. It is completely asynchronous – that is it uses `TcpClient`’s methods `ConnectAsync/Close/ReadAsync/WriteAsync` to connect/disconnect/read/write respectively.
My GUI has the Connect and Disconnect buttons. The Connect button disconnects and then immediately connects:

```
Disconnect();
Connect();
```

The Disconnect button only disconnects:

```
Disconnect();
```

Scenario 1: press Connect.
Scenario 2: press Disconnect and then press Connect.
The problem I’m facing is that Scenario 1 duly disconnects but only connects after that if I add a delay of about 100 ms:

```
Disconnect();
Thread.Sleep(100);
Connect();
```

The second scenario always works, which is of course expected, since the “manual” delay would be much longer than 100ms.
The connection code calls `TcpClient.ConnectAsync()`, and waits for the task’s completion.
The task completes normally; I also check 3 other things after its completion:

```
Debug.Assert(TcpClient.Connected);
Debug.Assert(TcpClient.Client.Connected);
Debug.Assert(IsConnected(TcpClient.Client));
…
bool IsConnected(TcpClient.Client)  // fairly well-known way to check a connection
{
    bool blockingState = client.Blocking;
    try
    {
        var bytes = new byte[1];
        client.Blocking = false;
        var bytesSent = client.Send(bytes, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        // 10035 == WSAEWOULDBLOCK
        if (e.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035))
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        client.Blocking = blockingState;
    }
}
```

However the server listening for connections does not “hear” the client’s connection attempt: evidently, it needs some time to “recuperate” from the disconnection.
Now my question: is the above situation normal and I indeed should introduce some delay between disconnecting and connecting?

Comment: You might want to indicate what language you are using here.

Comment: The situation you are describing is normal.  For the disconnection to complete, a total of packets have to be sent in both directions.  If you try an immediate reconnection, the attempt occurs in the middle of those three packets, before the connection is fully disconnected.

Comment: @Warren: yes I can understand that disconnection takes some time. What I can't understand though is why all 3 checks I mentioned report that connection has already been established.

Comment: Disconnect is needed only if your reusing the socket. Does your server  side socket is also set to reuse?